# flash app calling javascript functions stops suspends processing when Javascript alert() is called

Tags: javascript

I have a flash application that is making javascript calls at various intervals.

for QA we want to display what args the flash app called the javascript.

The original developer used alert.  however that stops the app from functioning until the ok button is clicked.( not what we wanted).  Trying the other dialogs.  those also stopped the app.

**I need a browser independent way (IE6+,  safari, some really old version of firefox+, opera) to display what the flash app sends to javascript and not have it stop my flash app.**

I thought about console.log(), but IE6 does not support that.

**I am hoping someone can give me an alternative to writing a div in the page and having the javascript dump the message in the div.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while the second option is technically viable.  politically at the company... no.
we ended up placing a div tag on the page, then having the the javascript that listens to the events append to the innerhtml of that div....

Answer (score 0):

You could check with conditional comments if IE6 or another platform that doesn't support console.log is being used, and if that is the case then include Firebug Lite

You can just do something like this:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

or in JavaScript (maybe more reliable if you're using other platforms than IE6 which doesn't support the console object

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(!console || !console.log) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js';

    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
</script>
```

and then use console.log as usual - Alert is *not* the way to debug!

Comment: i'll check with qa mgt.  see if they would be ok with installing firebug-lite on thier boxes.

Comment: There is no need to "install" firebug-lite. It is just a simple script/bookmarklet. There's no "local-installation" just a script tag or a bookmarklet. See http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable